# Installing Hadoop -- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I am following instructions on [website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation) to install Hadoop. However, I am stuck on the "# set to the root of your Java installation
  `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest` " part. How do I figure out the root on Ubuntu?

Comment: What's the error you are getting..?

Answer (score 2):

> > set to the root of your Java installation

Above statement is saying you to point to the `jdk` installation folder. Lets say you have `jdk` extracted to `/opt/java/` as `jdk1.8.0_60` then the `export` option should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_60
```

But if you have installed `java` using `ubuntu commands` then you can find the `java` installed path with `whereis` or `which` commands. for example

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Which showed that `java` is installed in `/usr/bin/java` so your `export` line should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
```

But I suggest you to follow the first step by downloading the appropriate version of `java`, and following the first way I mentioned above.

Hope the answer is helpful